# How to visualize character vectors in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to visualize some analysis using functions like Boxplot, hist, density etc on some data. The problem is that all of the columns are character vectors.

Here is a sample dataset https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3cafW7J7xSfNmhJQzh3SF9VYms/edit

Here is what I tried and got the error:

```
str(x$Accident_Severity)
Factor w/ 3 levels "fatal","serious",..: 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 ...
x$color[x$Accident_Severity=="fatal"]<-red
#Error: object 'red' not found
x$color[x$Accident_Severity=="fatal"]<-"red"
x$color[x$Accident_Severity=="serious"]<-"blue"
x$color[x$Accident_Severity=="slight"]<-"green"
dotchart(x$Weather_Conditions,labels=row.names(x$Accident_Severity),cex=.7,groups= x$Accident_Severity,
+          main="No. of acc",
+          xlab="weather", gcolor="black", color=x$color)
#Error in dotchart(x$Weather_Conditions, labels = row.names(x$Accident_Severity),  : 'x' must be a numeric vector or matrix
```

Comment: `Accident_Severity` is not a column in your linked-to data file.

Comment: btw a factor with 3 levels is not a character vector. If you have a genuine character vector with e.g. people's surnames or free-form opinions about joking in April then you need a completely different kind of visualization.

Comment: @hrbrmstr, I'm not seeing a `Weather_Conditions` column either.  Am I wrong?

Comment: @hrbrmstr my apologies.. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3cafW7J7xSfSkRTYWRWMHhaU2c/edit?usp=sharing here.. What I am trying to ask here is how to use the methods of numeric vector visualization with character vectors.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

`plot(x$Accident_Severity)` will make you a box plot illustrating the distribution. or `pie(table(x$Accident_Severity))` will make a pie chart. You should think about what you want and what makes sense - for example, with some cheating you could make a histogram with normal distribution density line but that wouldn't make sense.

### edit

If you want to use `density` or `hist` then these are by definition for continuous variables (see `[probability density function][1]` and [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) from wikipedia). So the only way is convert your character vectors into something that you can meaningfully treat as continuous variables. Length (number of characters) of a text string is naturally numeric; factor with levels "tiny", "small", "regular", and "huge" is ordinal but in some contexts (e.g if there are many levels or it can be thought of as a "polytomized" but naturally continuous variable and you just want the picture as an illustration) it may make sense to treat it as numeric / continuous - depend on what you want to achieve.

Using `unclass` on a factor will convert it to numeric - whether the result makes sense depends on how your levels are ordered (check it with `levels`).

Comment: yes, I know what I am doing, I am just asking how to use the above mentioned functions with character or string vectors

Comment: sorry but this is not clear. if you want to cheat R into believing that your not-numbers are actually numbers then assign a numeric value to each factor level or each possible value of your character vector. you can NOT make a histogram of character or factor data because it is "... an estimate of the probability distribution of a continuous variable ..." (Wikipedia) - so the only way is to convert your variable to numeric, if that makes sense. if not, then there's no way. or you can do a barplot (see my answer above) which looks a lot like a histogram and will definitely make sense.